# Unable to open admin panel after successful installation of magento on localhost in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: magento2, error, installation

I am trying to setup magento on my localhost. I followed all the instructions from here: http://www.unixmen.com/install-magento-ubuntu-15-04/ and successfully installed magento.

[image]

But i am unable to open admin panel and getting following error:

> The requested URL /admin_eoyh6q/ was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

I am able to open store home page but seems like some css is missing and none of the links present on this page are working and giving same error as admin panel.

I am using Magento 2 and have unzipped my `Magento-CE-2.0.2+sample_data-2016-01-28-02-46-48.tar.gz` in `/var/www/html`.

I am using Magento for the first time so i might be missing some basic steps, kindly guide me on this.

Comment: frontend css js not working right

Comment: What if you add index.php to the URL before the admin path?

Comment: No it didn't helped either.

Comment: @Kothari how can i resolve this issue of frontend css js ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: Doesn't work as the di.xml already has this code

Comment: Run this command in your root directory sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

You need to give permissions to magentoroot/var folder and magentorooot/pub folder.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R var/
sudo chmod 777 -R pub/
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks but it didn't resolved the issue.

Comment: This won't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure .htaccess is there in application root folder. If not then add a .htaccess file in application root folder. It will work.